# Android keyboard only shows up once in android

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAzMb.png

I have 2 tab. When I click to TAB Search. It will show keyboard and allow Enter keyword.

I want. when click to TAB Feed and back TAB Search. Keyboard not show.(hide keyboard)

Please. Help me!

Comment: Edit the question with your code , else it won't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this code:To force the soft keyboard to appear, you can use as below.

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```